# Splint: Parsing Error at the time of static checking

Tags: parsing, splint

I am new to static checking and I am assigned a task to do static checking of C code. I am given the liberty to select any one tool keeping in mind that the organisation already uses lint so a lint based tool should be preferred.

I selected splint because it is a free software. (PC lint and Lint being commercial)

Now I tried compiling a simple C file which had `#include <unistd.h>`

```
Splint shows error: 
/usr/include/unistd.h:221:26: Parse Error:
Suspect missing struct or union keyword: __ssize_t :
int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
```

Cannot continue.
How can I get this working?

I read in some places that splint doesn't support C99 standard whereas some says it supports. Can anyone tell me whether I should reconsider my choice as I will be using C99 format. What are the other free alternatives which are very similar to lint/splint?